# Was the question closed as General Refence?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I just came across [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48780/darth-vader-returns-to-the-jedi), and it was closed as "off-topic". It appears from the comments that it was closed essentially as General Reference or Too Trivial, both of which I thought had been burniated.

It does seem like a simple question, but if it wasn't obvious to the asker (and it is clearly a sci-fi...err science fantasy question), then it probably was not obvious to others. I can see a detailed answer, probably with spoilers, detailing Vader's turn to the darkside and then Luke's influence on turning him back. Probably not worthy of a Great Answer badge, but a solid answer nonetheless.

So why was this closed?

Comment: I've just reopened it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pureferret reopened it.  We don't close questions due to lack of research on the part of the question asker.